# What is the input of calculating signal noise ratio (SNR) and detective quantum efficiency (DQE) in estimation of imaging system?

Tags: radiation, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography, medical-physics, image-processing

In its definition, the [signal noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) (SNR) is the ratio of the mean siganl to the standard deviation of the noise. However, for a given picture what is the noise? The [detective quantum efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detective_quantum_efficiency) (DQE) is the ratio of the squared output SNR to the squared input SNR of the imaging detector. it also needs the noise value? I am confused how to access the noise? For x-ray image performance estimation, what is the inputs for calculating the SNR and DQE. Is the detected number of photons or the pixel value of the output image(closed to scanned object) generated by the x-ray imaging system needed? I thought its the final image needed to caluculate the SNR and DQE, but how can an image have noise value. The noise is mainly coming from the fluctuation of the detected number of photons. since only definition available without a concrete example, I still don't know how to calculate these quanlities step by step.
Hope people here with expertise can give a favour.

Comment: Reference 12 in the wikipedia article is the IEC standard . Annex C Shows how they compute the input noise power spectrum.  This paper https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s12194-013-0215-4.pdf walks though how they make measurements.  The input noise spectrum appears to come from the assumption that it is a Poisson distribution. If SNR goes as square root of N, then SNR squared goes as N. So you measure the incident flux. For the x-rays they correct for the air kerma since not all x-rays reach the detector.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of the reverse of what you posted.  Once you assume Poisson distribution of arriving photons, you can walk thru the standard equations of statistics to derive the formula relating DQE to the various SNRs observed.

UVphoton's comment pretty much fills in the details.